# Get Country Code/Name on Flutter Web for correct currency

Tags: flutter

Is there any way I can get the country code on Flutter Web? I need it to show the correct currency for the user, therefore, getting the language won't help me.

I also can't use `Localizations.localeOf(context)` because I'm not using localization in my app.

Using `Platform.localeName` of the `dart:io` package works only on mobile, not on web.

Any ideas?